# UWP using seperate project for Repository and Services but cant add reference to the application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, win-universal-app

Basically the question above, how would i go about adding a reference to the two projects, Repository and Service, which both are Class libraries that target the DNXcore50. They also have references to .net framework 4.5.1. I got the Libraries to talk to each other, and can call them from a web based api/application, but when I try and add the service layer reference to the UWP application I get an error message saying "The servicelayer cannot be referenced."

Here is the project.json files for both Repository and Service layer

Repository:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Testing.Data Class Library",
  "authors": [ "" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer.Design": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
  },
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  }
}
```

And Service Layer:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "AutoMapper": "4.2.0",
    "Testing.Data": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",

    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final"

  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

I have tried setting the both projects to output a dll and have copied them into the directory of the application but visual studio still refuses to pick that up.

Comment: Why is your service layer declared as application?

Comment: I think I changed it because i could not get the service layer to reference the repository class library. Let me see what I can work with here real quick. It was also so i would be able to host the service layer on the server

Answer (score 1):

Your service layer target framework moniker (TFM) seems wrong. `dnx451` and `dnxcore50` are used for applications (i.e. ASP.NET web project or unit-test project).

For Class Libraries you have to use `net451` and `dotnet5.4` (for now, going to change again with new RC).

See [this announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/98) for ASP.NET 5/Core RC1.

Comment: I would like to add that even if that wasn't the case, the dependencies which are required are not compatible with UWP.
Except:
"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer.Design": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final"

Comment: Are you saying that you can not use entity framework with a UWP.

Comment: Well according to the net standard platform (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md) UWP is netstandard 1.3 (this equals `dotnet5.4` as dotnet monikers are always 1 off. So `dotnet5.1` = netstandard 1.0). so an package that was created for UWP (`dotnet5.4`) should be able to be used in ASP.NET Core too. From the same link you can also see the target moniker for UAP: `uap10` and/or `netcore50`. Be aware that the lnked dumentation currently refers to the currently unreleased RC2 version and netstandard` moniker is not available in dnx/rc1

Comment: they are still named `netxxx` and `dotnetx.x` in RC1.